# Why Am I getting Variable Undefined in VBA For Each Loop

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I have been getting a large number of answers from Stackoverflow and I really appreciate all of the information you experts have provided!  This is my first time asking a question - so thank you.

I am running various VBA programs in the backend of a large Excel 2010 workbook and I am completely stumped on my current issue.  In a Module, I have a public sub with a For Each loop that iterates through a variant which is loaded with a range of string values in a worksheet.

When I run this loop, I either get an immediate compile error "Variable not defined" and the for each variable is highlighted or the program runs but loops without end.  I have literally commented everything out in the loop itself and I still get this issue.  When the loop does run, I see the string value being correctly retrieved into the for each variable.  If I comment out the loop then the sub runs without any issues.

Here is what I have to be clear:

```
Dim showWord as String
showWord = ""
For Each thisWord In allWords
     'showWord = CStr(thisWord)
     'MsgBox showWord
Next x
```

Now I have this exact same loop elsewhere in a different module and it always runs without issue.  I did change both the for each variable and variant variable names but that was it.

Can somebody please help me figure out what is going on here?

Thank you.

Comment: Stupid question:  have you already defined `thisWord` and `allWords` earlier in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you didn't define your variable allWords, as follow

```
Dim showWord as String
showWord = ""

dim allWords as (wtv)
allWords = (something)

'if not allWords is nothing then
  For Each thisWord In allWords
     'showWord = CStr(thisWord)
     'MsgBox showWord
  Next x
'end if
```

Answer (score 3):

your loop doesn't end because in `Next x` must be the same variable you are looping, something like this `Next ThisWord` and you must declare `allWords`.

```
Dim showWord as String
showWord = ""

For Each thisWord In allWords
    ....
Next thisWord
```

Comment: Good catch! That was completely missed by the original responder (and hte OP it seems!).